# Angular 9 Using recursive component, new components have old inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion

Note that im just starting to learn Angular 9:

I'm trying to create a tree using a recursive component. On every recursive call component gets a different object on `@input` and using `ngOnChanges` does some math and updates that object.

First tree generation is fine, but when generating second and more times values are multiplying. From what I saw,item corresponding values retain value from previous tree generation that was changed on `ngOnChanges()`

Here's code:
Recursive Component ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { IItem, IComponent } from 'src/app/item';
import { notEqual } from 'assert';
import { ItemsService } from 'src/app/items.service';

@Component({
    selector:'sf-production2',
    templateUrl:'./production.component2.html',
    styleUrls:['./production.component2.css']
})

export class ProductionComponent2 implements OnChanges{
@Input() item: IItem
items: IItem[]
@Input() amountNeeded: number;
inputs: IComponent[];

constructor(private itemService: ItemsService){
    this.items=itemService.getItems();
}

GetItemByName(name: string){
    return this.items.find(x=>x.name === name);
}

ngOnChanges(){
    console.log(`${this.item.name}`)
    if(this.item.components != null)
    {this.item.components.forEach(element => {
        console.log(`${element.name}:${element.inputPerMinute}`)
        element.inputPerMinute = element.inputPerMinute * (this.amountNeeded/this.GetItemByName(this.item.name).outputPerMin)

    });}

}
}
```

Recursive Component html;

```
<div *ngFor='let component of item.components'>
    <ul>
        <img src='{{GetItemByName(component.name).img}}'> {{component.inputPerMinute}}
        <sf-production2 *ngIf='GetItemByName(component.name).components' [item]='GetItemByName(component.name)' [amountNeeded]='component.inputPerMinute'></sf-production2>
    </ul>
</div>
```

item.ts

```
export interface IItem{
    name: string;
    img: string;
    components: IComponent[];
    outputPerMin: number;
}

export interface IComponent{
    name: string;
    inputPerMinute: number;
}
```

Recursive component gets called for the first time in app.component

`<sf-production2 [item]='selectedItem'  [amountNeeded]='2'></sf-production2>`

Did i miss something crucial? Am i doing it right?

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz to with a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Solved it! I was operating on references, thus updating my database. When calling component again the databse was already modified bringing different results

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the constructor that gets the data from the database is called only once and after that you are constantly operating on the same objects, not on their copies. By such the values that you are updating persist when you select the same object twice.

Comment: I think that was exactly it!. I was operating on references all along :/ Tried to clone inputs before working on them but finally settled on doing maths while displaying and not storing calculated numbers anywhere.